# JAVA : how to send and receive Json String using HTTP from Client To Server and vice versa

Tags: java, json, file, sockets, http

client programming over sockets in java but im new in HTTP client-server apps .

however im trying to write client-server application which the client should be able to send messeges to server and hear the result back and they should be able to send and receive files .
what i've done so far is creating a Server using `com.sun.net.httpserver` ( which i dont know if is suitable or not , it was the only thing i could find a good tutorial for it ):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(t.getHttpContext());
        String response = "This is the response";
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

and i could successfully create a connection to this server using `java.net.URL` and `java.net.HttpURLConnection` .
but i dont know how should i send and recieve strings and files on both sides ! and i couldn't even find a good complete tutorial for that .

so now i wish someone to give me a simple example on how to do that ?
or if there is any good and easy to learn library i can use for this ? ( of course i need some tutorials first )

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is an http server example that sends files. 
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-have-a-simple-http-server.html

Comment: i know how to do it with sockets . but sockets does not provide NAT traversal .

Comment: @MohammadSiavashi Check the updated answer, is that what your attempting?

Comment: Yep somehow it helps . But i need to know how to send and recieve strings . And most importantly on client side . Because there no tutorial for client side

Comment: @MohammadSiavashi Wouldn't this be client side? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582317/how-to-send-a-string-to-a-http-server-java